# Installing PEPS in ubuntu (Digital Ocean)

Tags: 14.04, server, mail, ssl

In Reference to this [manual](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-your-own-mail-server-and-file-storage-with-peps-on-ubuntu-14-04), I am trying to install PEPS on ubuntu and did the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/MLstate/PEPS
cd PEPS
echo mail.mydomain.com > domain
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install make
make build
```

Then, I got this message:

```
Removing intermediate container b2b0d8ffb335
Successfully built 325e46a054cb
```

Then, I made a temporary certificate using:

```
make certificate
```

The keys are stored in the `PEPS` directory as server.key and server.cert etc. What is the next step? I cannot see PEPS under : `https://mail.mydomain.com`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo make run
```

[An Article from the PEPS Team at MLstate](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-your-own-mail-server-and-file-storage-with-peps-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.